# Boot manager shows two entries but only one partition remains after restore

Tags: software-raid, windows-server-2019, boot-loader

I had to perform a recovery (using veeam recovery agent) on a windows 2019 server instance.

*Before* the recovery the system was configured as software raid (mirroring) with two dynamic disks.

After the recovery **only one disk remained and is now a basic disk** (no dynamic disk anymore) and there is no raid anymore.

But when booting the boot manager still shows **two entries** (see image).[image: Boot Manager]

Booting works, but it's strange that the boot manager shows two entries whereas there's only one disk remaining.

How do I fix the boot manager to **show only the one existing entry** (the only one remaining)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bcdedit /delete` to remove entries from the list.

bcdedit /delete /?

This command deletes an entry from the boot configuration data store.

bcdedit [/store ] /delete  [/f] [/cleanup | /nocleanup]

```
<filename>      Specifies the store to be used. If this option is not
                specified, the system store is used. For more information,
                run "bcdedit /? store".

<id>            Specifies the identifier of the boot entry that you want to
                delete. For more information about identifiers,
                run "bcdedit /? ID".

/f              Deletes the specified entry. Without this option, Bcdedit
                will not delete any entries that have a well-known
                identifier.

/cleanup        Deletes the specified entry and removes the entry from the
                display order. Any other references to the entry being
                deleted will also be removed from the store.  When deleting
                an OS loader entry, the associated resume from hibernation
                entry is also deleted if it is not referenced by any other
                OS loaders. This option is assumed unless /nocleanup is
                specified.

/nocleanup      Deletes the specified entry without removing the entry from
                the display order.
```

Examples:

The following command deletes the specified operating system entry from the
store and removes the entry from the display order:

```
bcdedit /delete {cbd971bf-b7b8-4885-951a-fa03044f5d71}
```

The following command deletes the specified operating system entry from the
store and removes the entry from the display order:

```
bcdedit /delete {cbd971bf-b7b8-4885-951a-fa03044f5d71} /cleanup
```

The following command deletes the specified operating system entry from the
store without removing the entry from the display order:

```
bcdedit /delete {cbd971bf-b7b8-4885-951a-fa03044f5d71} /nocleanup
```

The following command deletes the NTLDR based OS loader entry from the store:

```
bcdedit /delete {ntldr} /f
```